# how to list modified files by a certain user in a branch while excluiding all xml files using GIT?

Tags: git

I have this issue, I am working a in project with GIT.

When the feature takes too much time I always update my develop branch(its a kind of gitflow) and later I merge all those changes from develop to my feature branch.

It works fine and all.

But once done this, the history of commits that I merged and commited into my feature branch will appear there.

Example:
I did 2 commits, after I updated and merged my branches, at my branch history will appear my first 2 commits and other N commits made by other users but since I merged and commited into my branch... they will appear there.

How can I list only commits made by me? is there any way to do this in stash as well?

And I dont know if there is any way to do this without showing a certain type of file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use squash concept which will merge all the commits by a single signature. For an instance if you have 5 commits in your dev branch then merging them by squash will show only one commit in your feature branch.

`git merge --squash`

Comment: is there any way to filter to avoid showing all the .xml files?

Comment: If you can put xml files under ignore list of git which will not show any changes in xml. I'm not sure I've answered your question.

Comment: is there any way to do it from the command line just for the current consult?

Answer (score 0):

Will `git log --author <author>` work for you? Seems like the simplest approach to me.